# Realizar Input Radio como un Slide en su transicion

Tags: html, css3

Por favor su ayuda con el css, ya que estoy intentando realizar una transición tipo slide en un Input tipo Radio, pero solo logro la transición hacia el select izquiero, pero cuando intento el movimiento hacia la derecha, no realiza dicha transición slide, solo se selecciona normal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación adjunto el codigo:

```
<div class="form__group radio">
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="inc" value="inc" class="form__radio" checked />
  <label for="inc" class="form__label">Ingreso</label>
  <input type="radio" id="exp" value="exp" name="type" class="form__radio" />
  <label for="exp" class="form__label">Gasto</label>
</div>
```

```
.form__group .form__radio {
  display: none;
}

.form__group.radio {
  background-color: var(--third);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: var(--primary);
}

.form__group .form__radio + .form__label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center; 
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form__group .form__radio + .form__label::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: .8rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  transition: left .4s ease-in;
}

.form__group .form__radio:nth-child(1) + .form__label::before {
  left: 100%;
}

.form__group .form__radio:nth-child(2) + .form__label::before {
  left: 0;
}

.form__group .form__radio:checked + .form__label::before {
  background-color: var(--secondary);
  left: 0;
}
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que el efecto se mantenga, solo un elemento debe moverse y mantener el background (en el ejemplo, solo el primer `label`). Este elemento recibe la transicion para ambos sentidos.

Ademas para que haya transision debe haber un valor por inicial definido `left: 0` en `.form__group .form__radio + .form__label::before {`

```css
* {
  --secondary: #aaa;
  --third: #ccc;
  --primary: #080;
}

.form__group .form__radio {
  display: none;
}

.form__group.radio {
  background-color: var(--third);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: var(--primary);
}

.form__group .form__radio + .form__label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center; 
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form__group .form__radio + .form__label::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: .8rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  transition: left .4s ease-in;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.form__group .form__radio:nth-child(1) + .form__label::before {
  background-color: var(--secondary);
  left: calc(100% + 0.5rem);
  border: 1px solid green;  
}

.form__group .form__radio:nth-child(2) + .form__label::before {
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;  
}

.form__group .form__radio:checked + .form__label::before {
  
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form__group radio">
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="inc" value="inc" class="form__radio" checked />
  <label for="inc" class="form__label">Ingreso</label>
  <input type="radio" id="exp" value="exp" name="type" class="form__radio" />
  <label for="exp" class="form__label">Gasto</label>
</div>
```

Agregué colores de borde para mostrar cual es el elemento recibiendo la transicion (borde verde)